# Sticky list items at RTL direction

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custom XML layout for an android app and I got this problem where there is a "tools:listitem", when I'm trying to make it rtl the items become sticky to each other, I attached two images one when it's LTR and the other when it's RTL.

RTL: [RTL-BUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hovw9.png)

LTR: [LTR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn1KT.png)

the fragment code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvTasks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layout_margin"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/mid_view_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/mid_view_padding"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_task"/>
```

the item code

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contentBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_task_rounded_view"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/half_layout_margin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_layout_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaskAward"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/empty_dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/task_logo_size"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_layout_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/half_layout_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_task_flag"
        android:textSize="@dimen/award_text_size"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/tiny_view_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivTaskLogo"
        tools:text="+10"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTaskLogo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/task_logo_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/task_logo_size"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_tasks_logo_image"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/bg_tasks_card"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTaskNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_layout_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivTaskLogo"
        tools:text="Zadanie #80"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTaskStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_layout_margin"
        android:text="@string/tasks_btn_title_start"
        android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTaskNumber"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> ```
````

Comment: How are you adding Margin to the Items of recyclerView ? Are you using any `MarginDecorator`? if yes then add it with question

Comment: @ADM no there is no MarginDecorator in the code

Comment: Add margin end to ViewRoot item

Comment: @Sajad Hosseini Can you explain the answer on my code please cause I'm just messing up with the code I have no experience

Comment: How is this space is showing in `LTR` layout then ? there should be a margin added somewhere .

Comment: Let me ask some questions. Do you have a recycler view? And these pictures are list items of recycler view?

Comment: @ADM I'm a web developer, I know there is something somewhere. It took me 4 hours to tell myself no need to continue I just need to ask if anyone knows where to find this margin

Comment: @SajadHosseini yes I believe so, I'll edit the question

Comment: @iRedux Add android:marginEnd="8dp" in ConstraintLayout

Comment: @SajadHosseini Thanks it's working but It's not a good solution cause these areas https://prnt.sc/12ksbzm are now bigger, so the lists are now narrower. and if I try to use this solution in another place look what would happen https://prnt.sc/12ksdjc

Comment: @iRedux It seems this is a different recycler view with a different list items.